# Relay Voltage and Current

Tags: relay, dc-motor

I am using a 5V relay for switching ON/OFF a starter motor. The motor draws 12V/16A to run. The relay has the specification as shown below. My question is will this relay work or it will burn due to large current drawn by the motor ? [image]

Comment: We have the battery specs, I suppose. (Though they seem a little "off" to me.) But we don't have the motor specs. Can you provide them?

Comment: I am curious about the specification of the load (motor). The relay can savely interrupt a 10 A DC current. Does your load grant to draw less than that at any time?

Comment: The motor draws 12v/16A for powering up.

Comment: @EKANSHSHARMA you are saying that the spec you put in “battery” (which don’t look like battery specs) are actually the start-up current on the motor? Is that because the battery is limiting the current? What is the steady-state motor current? Could you edit the question to clarify?

Comment: @EdgarBrown I have corrected the question. But I don't know about steady-state motor current. I am new to this.

Comment: The moment the relais is closing its contacts is the moment when it is most vulnerable to overcurrent, because contacts bounce. You have to use at least a 25A relais for a motor which draws 16A on startup.

Answer (score 1):

If the motor takes 16A and clearly marked on the relay is 10A then what do you think...

if it does work, it may not work for very long or many cycles...

You need to use a larger relay, there are some that do 50A or more - diesel engine heater plug relays for example, just need to check component listings by the suppliers.

Edit based on comments:
Sizing a relay for this type of situation requires that the power, voltage and current limits are all respected.

So, in this case the relay is fine for 12v, but not for the current.

Comment: I thought that it might compensate and handle it because the voltage drawn by the motor is 12 v at 16 amps and the relay can handle 30v at 10 amps. Actually I don't know much. @Solar

Comment: No, voltage is increased to reduce current to use lighter / thinner components. So get the correct ones...

Comment: Would you mind telling me whether this relation ( P=V*I) is valid in this case? I am confused because I am new to this.

Comment: You need to choose components that satisfy all 3, P, V & I at the same time, not just one.

Comment: Thank you. You've cleared all my doubts. i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic answers to this: (1) as an engineer designing a system that has to work reliably and (2) as a hobbyist that is ok trying a hack that *might* work and bumped into that relay in ono of his drawers.

- As an engineer

Hell no!! Pushing 16A through a part that is specified for 10A is blatantly insane.

I might change my opinion if I saw more detailed specs on the relay and the motor, but just the chance of having to interrupt 16A  with that relay is way too much risk.

- As a hobbyist

The motor would present an inductive load with reduced current in contact closure and, assuming the motor doesn’t stall, would have a steady state current that is very likely to be less than 10A by the time the relay opens (NTS: make sure to add a diode for the inductive kickback or that relay is a goner)

Making sure to time the relay properly we can avoid having to interrupt 16A, hoping that the motor doesn’t stall. The 16A would circulate for a relatively short time that should lead to little contact heating in the relay.

The contacts have some likelihood of fusing together, but we might be able to get more than one operation out of it. If we get lucky it might even survive for more than 100 cycles!!

What’s the worst that can happen? A few flames? A burnt motor?